# Grep db_name from codeigniter configuration

Tags: php, regex, awk, sed, grep

I created a script to backup database and system in separate directory, the directory will contain the system and its database. So I need to know what database the system had/use.

My whole project is using codeigniter framework, I see that database information is defined on `database.php`, so what Im trying to do is pulling database name into my bash script.

So far, I can only do this.

```
$ grep -F "['default']['database']" config/database.php 
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydatabase';
```

I need to extract **`mydatabase`** and left out other parts, how would I do that with grep/sed/awk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
$ grep -F "['default']['database']" config/database.php | cut -d = -f 2- | cut -d \' -f 2
mydatabase
```